# Sorting data from MySQL by SUM with Grouping By - not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have a problem with mysql - i'm kind new to it, byt looking to improve my skills :)

Have a code like this:

```
if($where > 0) $query = mysql_query("SELECT img.*, user.user as owner_name, cat.name as cat_name FROM tentego_img AS img LEFT JOIN tablicacms_users AS user ON user.id = img.owner LEFT JOIN tentego_img_cat AS cat ON cat.id = img.cat WHERE img.`is_waiting` LIKE ".$where.$cat."  INNER JOIN tentego_img_vote ON tentego_img.id = tentego_img_vote.object_id GROUP BY tentego_img_vote.object_id ORDER BY SUM ( (CASE WHEN tentego_img_vote.vote = '0' THEN '-1' ELSE '1' END) ) DESC LIMIT ".$page.",".$objPerPage);
```

I need to make sorting by number of votes, sorted descending.
Still it makes results sorted by it own way.
In table I have rows:

```
ID - vote id for table purpose
object_id- id of object joined with another table to show results.
User ID - user id
Vote - where values are 0 for dislike and 1 for like (so -1 for 0, and +1 for 1)
```

So, as I understand i need to sum up all records for each of unique object_id, then sort by sum of vote values of each. 
This code worked before my script provider decide to upgrade it, so right now i dont know how to fix it :(

Comment: You have an error ?

Comment: There's no error. It's working but not sorting by total sum of votes made. 
All got phrased by browser, showing records only with votes, but got sorting from god know where ;D

Comment: This is the normal version I use for displaying materials at front page, sorted by date ` "if($where > 0) $query = mysql_query("SELECT img.*, user.user as owner_name, cat.name as cat_name FROM `tentego_img` AS img LEFT JOIN tablicacms_users AS user ON user.id = img.owner LEFT JOIN tentego_img_cat AS cat ON cat.id = img.cat WHERE img.`is_waiting` LIKE ".$where.$cat." ORDER BY img.`date` DESC LIMIT ".$page.",".$objPerPage); `